# Yolo V3 in Google Colab

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, google-colaboratory, setup.py, yolo

I have been trying to develop an object detection system using Yolo v3 on google Colab instead of my local machine because of its free, fast and open source nature. But the problem is I am getting lost after following few tutorials regarding Yolo V3 set up and development but none of them are for Google Colab specific. Now I am stocked after installing all the required dependencies in Colab.

Please forward me any good tutorials regarding the development process or guide me on this issue.

Some of the tutorials I have followed through are :

1. [How to implement a YOLO (v3) object detector from scratch in
   PyTorch](https://blog.paperspace.com/how-to-implement-a-yolo-v3-object-detector-from-scratch-in-pytorch-part-2/)
2. [Google Colab Free GPU Tutorial](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d)
3. [Using Pytourch](https://jovianlin.io/pytorch-with-gpu-in-google-colab/)
4. [YOLO on Google Colab](https://dev.to/kojikanao/yolo-on-google-colab-4b8e)

Comment: You can install packages using `pip` in a Google Colab environment. The rest of your code shouldn't really be that different. What difficulties are you facing? Please be more specific.

Comment: I did install all the dependencies there but I don't know how to run.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a post about how to train Yolo using Darknet on Google Colab. 
It contains the necessary steps, some tips and a notebook with all the explanations.

[Tutorial](http://blog.ibanyez.info/blogs/coding/20190410-run-a-google-colab-notebook-to-train-yolov3-using-darknet-in/)

NOTE: I think this can help, but maybe is not a good practice here in StackOverflow to link to an own tutorial. Sorry in advance!

David

Comment: Sorry for the late response @kriyeng. There are no proper tutorials regarding the use of framework to integrate it into an application.
So I guess it's ok to post a third party source regarding the question.

Answer (score 1):

**YOLO V3 - In 15 minutes **

Step - 1

Clone the repository `!git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet.git`

Set current directory `!cd darknet`

Check the current directory - `!pwd`

Note - if `!cd` not worked then use,

```
import os
os.chdir("path")
```

Step - 2

Open `darknet/makefile` by double tap on it.
Edit the file,change values `GPU = 1`

Scroll down

```
ARCH= -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
  -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
  -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] \
  -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52]
  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=[sm_20,sm_21] \ This one is deprecated?
```

Here in first line change `compute_30,code=sm_30` to `compute_50,code=sm_50`
save this file by `CTRL + S`

Step - 3

Now make a folder `darknet/data/Image` and move your dataset in this.
Both Image file and Annotation file.

> example - image.jpg and image.txt

split your dataset without moving your data into different folder just create two txt files  and store images names with there path.
example - data/Images/image.jpg

you can use code to write names in the txt file.
https://gist.github.com/sainisatish/1328a1d29273e32a5821cfbc38127fbe

> `train.txt` and `valid.txt` placed these files in `darknet/data` folder

Step - 4

Now open configuration file `darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg` and edit it.(double tap on it)

here is the model architecture.

> first change starting parameter like `Batch = 64,subdivision = 16`

max_batches = 2000*n , here n is the number of class
if you have 2 classes then `max_batches = 4000`.

step is the % of max_batches, we can use 80% and 90%

```
step = 80% of max_batches, 90% of max batches
step = 3200,3600
```

scroll down to the bottom and change two parameters

In `[yolo]` layer change - `classes`

and

In `[convolutional]` layer(Which is above only the [yolo] layer) change `filters`.

> classes = (c) you number of classes

> filter = (c+5)*3

Note - here is only 3 [yolo] layer

Save the file

Step - 5

Now create two files
In `darknet/data` create a file with `.names` extension and save your class name.

```
cat
dog
```

In `darknet/cfg` create another file with `.data` extension and save the below details.

```
classes= 2 
train  = data/train.txt
valid  = data/test.txt
names  = data/obj.names
backup = backup/
```

Now all work is completed.
Just run this command

```
!make
```

Download this weight file

```
!wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/darknet53.conv.74
```

After successful completion of the command
train the darknet model by running this command

```
!./darknet detector train cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov3.cfg darknet53.conv.74 | tee -a log.txt
```

test your model

```
./darknet detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov3.cfg backup/your weight file address
```

Facing any issue comment your question.